# @PreAuthorize not working in spring security 6.1.3 in spring 3.1.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am facing a problem using Spring security @PreAuthorize annotation. I have followed many tutorials and theorically I am making everything right but for some reasons it doesn't work.

All I wanted to do in this test was to have a public request (/hello) and 2 private requests, one for the users only (/boolean) and another one for the admin only (/number).
The private ones are correctly redirected to login but both /boolean and /number work with both credentials.
If I call /boolean with the user I am getting User Authorities: [ROLE_USER], but if I use admin credentials it logs User Authorities: [ROLE_ADMIN] as if the @PreAuthorize didn't exists.
Same behaviour for the /number.

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/api/security")
public class BaseController extends HateosController{
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public final String getHello() {
        return "Ciao!";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/boolean")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public final boolean getBoolean(Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("User Authorities: " + authentication.getAuthorities());
        return true;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/number")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public final Integer getNumber(Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("User Authorities: " + authentication.getAuthorities());
        return 115683;
    }
}
```

My SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin").password(encoder.encode("admin")).roles("ADMIN").build();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user").password(encoder.encode("user")).roles("USER").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/rest/api/security/hello").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .and().build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?
P.S: I know something in securityFilterChain is deprecated but it should work the same and i have tried also with newer methods with no results.

Comment: The problem is your methods are `final` those cannot be proxied and as security is applied through AOP which utilizes proxies your methods cannot be `final`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove final modifier on getBoolean and getNumber

Comment: Can't believe it was that little thing. Thank you so much